# PHPWord create nested list items with formatting text (textrun)

Tags: listitem, phpword

I am using [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) to create .docx file and generate nested list items.
I wrote the following code:

```
$listStyle = 'multilevel';
$phpWord->addNumberingStyle(
    $listStyle,
    array(
       'type'   => 'multilevel',
        'levels' => array(
            array('format' => 'upperLetter', 'text' => '%1.', 'left' => 360, 'hanging' => 360),
            array('format' => 'decimal', 'text' => '%2.', 'left' => 400),
        ),
    );
);
$prgphStyle = array('spaceBefore' => 0, 'spaceAfter' => 0);

$section->addText('Multilevel list.');
$section->addListItem('Part One:', 0, $boldStyle, $listStyle, $prgphStyle);
// here i want to add text
$section->addListItem('Item 1', 1, null, $listStyle, $prgphStyle);

//
$section->addListItem('Part Two:', 0, $boldStyle, $listStyle, array('spaceBefore' => 120, 'spaceAfter' => 0));
$item1Text = 'Item 1'; // can be formatted, like bold, italics
$section->addListItem("$item1Text ", 1, null, $listStyle, $prgphStyle);
$section->addListItem('Item 2', 0, null, $listStyle, $prgphStyle);
```

So I want to add textRun next to 'Part One' text, as inline, and formatted text in each item details, how I can fix this, please help.

Comment: what is it exactly that fails? I ran your code (which needs some fixes, missing $boldStyle variable and a ";" to much, and I get a result. Part 1 and Part 2 are in bold.

Comment: yes, i know it works, but i want to:
1) add formatted text following 'Part One' text, as one line, no break
2) to make $item1Text value with formatted text such as bold, italics and pass to $section->addListItem("$item1Text ", 1, null, $listStyle, $prgphStyle); as variable string

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add a ListItemRun:

```
$listItem = $section->addListItemRun(0, $listStyle, $prgphStyle);
$listItem->addText('Part One: ', $boldStyle);
// here i want to add text
$listItem->addText('normal Text');

$section->addListItem('Item 1', 1, null, $listStyle, $prgphStyle);
```